# How do you add sequential numbers to non-contiguous paragraphs in a google doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

In academic papers, examples of phenomena are often put in their own sequentially numbered paragraphs. These paragraphs aren't necessarily next to each other, but are scattered throughout the document. Here's a sample document with sequentially numbered paragraphs giving examples of the topic at hand:

> There are many languages, for example English (see example 1), Spanish
> (see example 2), Danish (see example 3). 
>
>  (1) Google Docs are cool.
>
>  (2) Los documentos google son geniales.
>
>  (3) Google Dokumenter er seje.
>
> Linguistics is the scientific study of languages, for example,
> Portuguese (see example 4): 
>
> (4) O português é bom.
>
> Languages, human and computer, are fascinating.

I know that static text can be inserted at the cursor in a google doc with:

```
function insertHelloWorld() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  cursor.insertText("Hello World!");
}
```

My question:
How can I keep track of numbers when they are inserted, so that I can update all numbers when a new example is inserted in the middle of text with already existing examples? So, if I were to insert a German example as number (2) above (between the English and Spanish examples), I want to update the example numbers that come after the newly inserted German example:

> ... 
> (1) Google Docs are cool. 
> (2) Google Text & Tabellen sind cool. 
> (3) Los documentos google son geniales. 
> (4) Google Dokumenter er seje.
>
> ... 
> (5) O português é bom. 
> ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a "reference" be the "(see example `n`)" string, where `n` is a number.

Let an "example" be the "(`n`) Example text..." where `n` is a number and this is always the beginning of a line.

This solution assumes that you have manually ordered your "references" and "examples".  The code does not reorder the list of examples.  Therefore, it doesn't matter what the current `n` values are, we just need to go through the whole Doc and apply sequential numbers.

This is easier to implement if you can forget all of your formatting when you run the update.  In that case, you can use regular JavaScript and apply `String.prototype.replace` to the entire body.  However, I'm assuming that you don't want to remove your formatting, so we are forced to use the `DocumentApp` model instead.

In my example, I am using `body.findText` to loop through the Doc.  This unfortunately uses regular expression *strings* instead of normal RegExp objects which require extra backslashes to find the literal parentheses.  Furthermore, I am using the `deleteText` and `insertText` text functions rather than `String.prototype.replace` because using `replace` will act on the entire element, not the start and end offsets found by the `findText` function.

```js
function updateSequentialReferences() {
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  replaceSequentially(body, "\\(see example \\d+\\)", count => `(see example ${count})`);
  replaceSequentially(body, "^\\(\\d+\\)(.*)$", (count, match) => match.replace(/^\(\d+\)/, `(${count})`));
}

function replaceSequentially(body, regexString, replacerFn) {
  let foundRef = body.findText(regexString);
  let count = 1;
  while (foundRef !== null) {
    const {element, end, start} = unwrapRangeElement(foundRef);
    const text = element.asText();
    const match = text.getText().slice(start, end + 1);
    text.deleteText(start, end);
    text.insertText(start, replacerFn(count, match));
    ++count;
    foundRef = body.findText(regexString, foundRef);
  }
}

function unwrapRangeElement(element) {
  return {
    element: element.getElement(),
    end: element.getEndOffsetInclusive(),
    start: element.getStartOffset(),
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was useful. Your code helped create the code [here](https://github.com/sethlb/example-numberer).